# LSTM- detach the hidden state

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I'm starting to study RNN, particularly LSTM, and there is part of the theory that I just don't understand.

When you stack LSTM cells, I see how everybody detaches the hidden state from history, but this makes no sense to me, aren't LSTM supposed to use hidden states from history to make better predictions?

I read the documentation but it still not clear to me, so any explanation is welcomed

Comment: You might want to make this a little more precise and include examples of what you mean. There is no such thing as "detaching states from history" in the _theory_ of RNNs (which is what you are referring to in the text). I suppose you are talking about pytorch code or something like that, in which case, again, (code) examples would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it right, the hidden state in the LSTMs is there to serve as a memory. But this question arises, are we supposed to learn them? No, hidden state isn’t suppose to be learned, so we detach it to let the model **use** those values but to **not** **compute** gradients.

If you don't detach, then the gradients will be really big.

Comment: Thanks! this was the explanation I was looking for

Comment: (In Pytorch) should I set the hidden state as buffer? Seems that a detached variable works well too.

Comment: I don't code with Pytorch much, but I'd try detaching first.@zheyuanWang